# Sending SOAP request to use your own services

Tags: java, javascript, xml, ajax, soap

I'm developing a web application in which we have provided some web-services as well.Being done with the *domain model*, we are now going to implement *UI* and *controller*.

The controller is going to be the JS code we have in our webpages. Meaning that in order to call our own web services, we need a JS library.
Can anyone please introduce one?

**UPDATE:**

For those dealing with the same challenge, I recommend using [SOAPjs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapjs/files/latest/download) library.

Comment: You want to send SOAP request using JS from browser and your server generates WSDL and SOAP response in JSP?

Comment: no! we don't use any JSP anymore. in other words, it's replaced with JS in the CTO's approach. The server will only reply to webservices through it's endpoints.

Comment: So your server is running on something like nodejs? where are you sending SOAP request from? Server or browser?

Comment: I just edited the workflow to make it more clear. The server only receives SOAP requests and responds to them. To be more precise, the JS is acting as the controller now that decides which request to send to which service.

Comment: This is really not a good idea unless the SOAP api is public. If its not where do you store the auth information.

Comment: and what if the SOAP API is public? and authorization is done in server independent from any SOAP?

Comment: Which server? the server which is serving your Javascripts or the server serving SOAP responses. SOAP server must do authentication. But you need to pass the authentication information from JS. This will expose your sensitive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For developer access to a SOAP based web service, I would highly recommend using [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/). The open source community edition is highly functional and can generate sample SOAP messages, by reading your services WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but at this point i'm not much concerned about load testing my web app, does SOAPUI introduce anything more than testing? :)

Comment: SOAPUI is a test tool, but it's also the best adhoc SOAP client I've ever used. It will read your WSDL and generate a template SOAP message. Try it out, I guarantee it's simpler to use compared to developing your own webapp to talk to your service.